# Dilemma to choose sqlite or Couchdb for app rewrite from native iOS to hybrid

Tags: sqlite, ionic3, angular5

I am rewriting the old native iOS app (objective C) in hybrid (Angular and ionic).
Native app used SQLite internally as a database. Now I have 2 options with me **1. Rewrite the database in Couchbase Lite.
2. Continue with SQLite similar to native.**

After brainstorming I thought that SQLite is the best option to go ahead with due to below points. Can someone provide more inputs into my design decision, if already had gone through same dilemma?

I am also looking out on below aspects for SQLite in context of hybrid app development.
**1.  Overall DB Size limitation on iOS and Android
2. Data retrieval size limitation for SQLite to confirm if it has any direct impact on performance
3. Concurrency scenarios
4. Can we reuse existing SQLite file in app bundle and continue post upgrade.
5. Data Encryption**

**1) Full Couch base mobile solution needs considerable middleware and deployment efforts. I have constraint that I can't have any middleware or backend layer efforts and have to just rewrite the frontend.  :-**
Merely having couch base Lite database in app does not provide any value and is similar to SQLite.
The couch base provide seamless upgrade support , sync facility and performance gain only if the full couch base solution is implemented which has below components. :-
-   Couch base Lite. (Mobile side NOSQL database).
-   Couch base Gateway (Middleware for implementation of sync)
-   Couch base Server (Central server who has the correct data which should be reflected on the devices through sync with gateway)
Gateway and server component needs to be developed from scratch and have deployment cost associated.

**2) Sync API reusability is nil if we go to couch base Lite implementation :-**
- If we use SQLite similar to native implementation, we can reuse the Sync APIs which are already developed and working fine an app. But if we need to implement Couch base Lite, we need to implement a new approach to sync using Gateway and Couch base server so we can’t reuse the existing middleware implementation here. We already have a sync mechanism implemented which is working fine with SQLite.

**3) Upgrade of existing iOS app needs extra efforts of converting the SQLite data in existing app bundle to Couch base format.**
 - Being NoSQL database Couch base is not compatible with SQLite database. So we need to implement the custom conversion module to convert the data. If we don’t do it, the local data is lost and we may have to re-sync whole data fresh and store it in Couch base format. It’s a unnecessary sync which may create performance or user experience issue post upgrade.

**4) Performance in CRUD operations :-**
The performance benchmarking suggests SQLite is much better option than Couch Base Lite. Refer the paper  link below for performance benchmarking.
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse544/13sp/final-projects/p19-tperrier.pdf